# Core-plot dynamic set xPlotRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I have a graph and I need to change its xPlotRange in process adding new elements. How can I do it?

I have tried this:

```
[self.hostView.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace 

setAllowsUserInteraction:YES];
```

---

```
long count = [array count];
if (count>100 && count<maxElements)
[self plotSpace:self.hostView.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace willChangePlotRangeTo:[CPTMutablePlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(0.0) length:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:count+100]] forCoordinate:CPTCoordinateX];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace*)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace; plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction=YES; plotSpace.delegate = self;

plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt(xAxisMin)/*minimum x value*/ lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt()];

plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt(60) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt(yAxisRange)];

[plotSpace setGlobalXRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt(xAxisMax - xAxisMin)]];

[plotSpace setGlobalYRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt([[_dict1 objectForKey:@"minValue"]intValue ]) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt(yAxisRange)]];
```